# ReferenceArrayInput inside FormDataConsumer does not provide data back

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I have this code:

```
                <ReferenceInput label="Tipus" source="type" reference="categories" validate={ required() } >
                    <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
                </ReferenceInput>
                <FormDataConsumer>
                    {({formData, ...rest}) => {
                        console.log(formData)
                        if ( formData.type !== undefined ) {
                            var t = formData.type;
                            var myType = t.toString();
                            var myOptionText = `${myType}.name`
                        }
                        return (
                                    <ReferenceArrayInput label="Categories dynamic" source={myType} reference="categories" {...rest}>
                                        <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
                                    </ReferenceArrayInput>
                        )
                       }}
                </FormDataConsumer>
```

I have my API data which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "21": [
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "Pontgyűjtő",
                "old_id": 0,
                "parent_id": 21,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "Akciós",
                "old_id": 1,
                "parent_id": 21,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "Aranykártya",
                "old_id": 2,
                "parent_id": 21,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "Kedvező tankolás",
                "old_id": 3,
                "parent_id": 21,
                "type": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Hitelkártya",
        "old_id": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "type": null
    },
    {
        "53": [
            {
                "id": 54,
                "name": "Minta alkategória",
                "old_id": 0,
                "parent_id": 53,
                "type": 90
            }
        ],
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Minta kategória",
        "old_id": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "type": null
    },
    {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Minta folyószámla kategória",
        "old_id": null,
        "parent_id": null,
        "type": null
    }
]
```

in console log I can see formData.type === my "id", so e.g. 21.

I want to reach the array of "21" with my ReferenceArrayInput, so I could choose from all the subcategories from it.

I also want to save it into my original categories source.

e.g. when I use constant values for my SelectArrayInput, my source is "categories"

```
const choices = [
    { id: 3, name: "Bla1" },
    { id: 4, name: "Bla2" },
    { id: 5, name: "Bla3" },
    { id: 6, name: "Bla4" },
    { id: 7, name: "Bla5" },
    { id: 8, name: "Bla6" },
    { id: 9, name: "Bla7" },
    { id: 0, name: "Bla8" },
    { id: 1, name: "Bla9" },
];

<SelectArrayInput source="categories" choices={choices} optionText="name" optionValue="id" validate={ required() } allowEmpty={false} />
```

So the whole goal of mine is to reach dynamically the choices from the categories REST API endpoint, choose from it, and save it in my original REST API endpoint (which is called "ads", into the categories field).

I know I do something wrong but even if I google'd for it I haven't found the solution. Maybe you could help me fix what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Reka, such a solution, even if it works, can create big problems in the future. Directories are usually done in a separate table (resource).

Comment: hm .. what kind of big problems are you referring to? Why would this not work? What are you suggesting? Should I hardcode something into the code that's in a DB already?

Comment: You simultaneously rule the reference table and refer to it. Usually directories are kept in separate tables.
We need to see what server requests go from react-admin and how data will be placed in the redux store.

Comment: hm okay ... so if my subcategories will come from a different Resource, it's easily doable from the API side, but i still don't really understand how can I save/store/send the data back to ads/categories field ...